# Laravel persistent permissions for php artisan config:cache file creation

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-9

I've followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel) to set permissions for Laravel 9 running on WSL2 through docker. Everything works great, but whenever I run

`php artisan config:cache`

The /bootstrap/cache/config.php file does not get updated as you would expect.

`ls -l` returns the following after running config:cache:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 26933 Nov 16 08:10 config.php`

The linked guide above sets the folder permissions to -rwxrwxr--, which then gets overrode by the config:cache command.

Is there any way to persist the permissions on this file without having to run chmod every single time I modify the .ENV or config files?

**EDIT**

After digging around some more, it looks like everything BUT the 'debug' variable is being updated in the bootstrap/cache/config.php file. Manually changing the debug value to true and re-running php artisan config:cache will revert debug back to false. I'm 100% sure my .ENV is set to true, as well as the backup in my config/app.php file. I'm running in the 'local' environment.

How do I get that debug value to persist?

Comment: Are you able to run the `artisan` command using the same user that is running the application?

Comment: @AaronT Yes, artisan is being run by www-data:www-data

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /bootstrap/cache/config.php
sudo chmod -R 777 /bootstrap/cache
```

You can also run

```
sudo php artisan config:clear
sudo php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: Even though I don't like setting stuff to 777, running config:cache just resets it back to what I wrote in my question. The artisan commands didn't make a difference either.